# Command is working in Console but Cronjob not work

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have this command to run in the cronjob

/bin/mkdir /var/www/html/webfiles/subdir/mobile/archives/$(date +%Y%m%d)

It creates current date folder fine.

But when i make it's cron like this example:
59 10 * * * /bin/mkdir /var/www/html/webfiles/subdir/mobile/archives/$(date +%Y%m%d)

It does not work at all ?

I have tried all things reboot, restart crond etc.

**Running from root user.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a crontab, the "%" character has to be escaped by backslash "\".

See the man page, `man 5 crontab`:

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a "%" character, will be executed by  /bin/sh  or  by  the shell  specified  in  the  SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: you mean this :  /bin/mkdir /var/www/html/webfiles/subdir/mobile/archives/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)

Answer (score -1):

@rudimeier Thanks for it.

I found one strange thing in tackle of this problem, when i edit crons via ftp clients like Winscp and save the crons it does not work.

When i did with nano editor via cli it worked.

Hopefully this might help some one else too.

Thanks